# Declare anf fill String[][] array

Tags: java, android, string, multidimensional-array

I have a problem, which does no exist (no error displayec on Eclipse). I try to declare two dimensional string and then dynamically fill them with data.
In main class:
    `public String[][] lista;`
And in onCreate:
`lista[0][0] = "55";`
    `lista[0][1] = "jacek";`
    `lista[0][2] = "miecz";`
    `lista[0][3] = "12";`

Unfortunately app crashes on startup until I leave only first declaration. I see no errors.

Comment: java arrays 101. not related to android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your array and set the size of each dimension `onCreate`

```
lista = new String[10][10];
lista[0][0] = "55";
lista[0][1] = "jacek";
lista[0][2] = "miecz";
lista[0][3] = "12";
```

---

You can't use an array without specifying its size. But you can use `ArrayList<String[]>` to store unknown number of rows of 1d arrays of fixed size.

Change `public String[][] lista;` to `ArrayList<String[]> lista` and update your `onCreate`

```
lista = new ArrayList<String[]>();
lista.add(new String[]{"55","jacek","miez","12"});//your example array of 4 elements
lista.add(new String[4]);//empty array for 4 elements
```

You can access it with `lista.get(row)[column]`

Comment: It may not be fixed. I know only one dimension (4 columns) and undefined number of rows.

Comment: If you don't know the number of rows you're better off using a variable-length data structure, such as an `ArrayList`, rather than an array.

Comment: so is it impossible to use dynamic arrays in android?

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined" number of rows?  If the number of rows will be determined later, but before you need to use the array, for example you have a variable `numRows` that contains the number of rows, you can use that to create the array: `lista = new String[numRows][4];` if every row will have 4 columns.  If you have to start using the array before you know how many rows it will be, then follow Jimmy's suggestion and use `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Lukis Java does not have the same kind of dynamic arrays that JavaScript, PHP, and Perl have.  It's because of the language, not because of Android.

Comment: Thanx for help!I just wonder why it doesn't throw an error if it couldn't work.

Comment: If you don't know the size of an array when you initialise it, but do after you fill it, then array is the wrong structure to use.  Lists and Maps are the way to go.